# Generating random terms from a grammar (simply typed lambda calculus)

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus, quickcheck

I have the following grammar representing the simply typed lambda calculus (STLC) in Haskell. I saw a lot of papers in the literature about how to generate random lambda terms but was wondering if there are any libraries in Haskell that can generate random instances from the grammar below? I am interested in generating the programs only once.

I saw a library called QuickCheck but can this be used for this purpose?

```
data Vtype = Tint
           | Tbool
           | Tfun Vtype Vtype
           deriving (Eq, Data)

data Expr = Vi Int
          | Vb Bool
          | Vv Name
          | App Expr Expr
          | Lam Vtype Name Expr
          deriving (Eq, Data)
```

My second question is, I know there are many benchmarks available for languages like Java and Python, but I tried looking for something like that for the lambda calculus and could not find anything. Is there any chance benchmarks for STLC or the untyped lambda calculus are available?

Comment: Yes there are libraries for this purpose https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-random you'll probably need to first learn how to use QuickCheck or some other randomness library though.

Comment: Do you want to generate only well-typed terms, or is garbage okay too?

Comment: Ideally well-typed terms, but even if not, I can probably work with any random terms then filter them with my type checker

Comment: You can do it using a [fair backtracking monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/control-monad-omega).  I wrote a [blog post](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2008/05/02/enumerating-a-context-free-language/) about it some years ago.

Comment: Not that his language includes `Lam`, a binding construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the QuickCheck library is what you need.

First I assume that `Name` is a type synonym for `String`?
Of course generating lambda terms in the STLC poses a particular problem. 
Quickcheck lets you generate terms in the `Gen` Monad, allowing for compositional generation of terms. Default `Gen`s for a Type can be declared by making said type instance of the typeclass `Arbitrary`. That is, once you have a generator of a nested type, you can use it to create a generator of a value constructor using it.

To give you an example, we could write a generator for a lambda abstraction taking a parameter of type `Tint` named x or y and returning a Bool (assuming you have written a generator `boolExpr`) as:

```
intLambda :: Gen Expr
intLambda = Lam Tint <$> elements ["x","y"] <*> (boolExpr :: Gen Expr)
```

(Note I am using Applicative Notation, which is often more elegant in this Monad.)

A good place to get started is [the hackage documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.13.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html) for the `Gen` module. A lot of QuickChecks modules are especially for executing the tests, which it seems is not your primary concern.

Comment: Note that this doesn't bother to produce semantically correct programs. As a result, the resulting generator will be very slow to generate non-trivial lambda terms. Also it is a little misleading in terms of hiding where the complexity lies: Coming up with `["x", "y"]` is the hard part here and depends on the result of `boolExpr` for any reasonable implementation.

Comment: @SebastianGraf That's why I said _generating lambda terms in the STLC poses a particular problem_. I gave a fairly bogus example only to show what the library is capable of. I definitely agree that writing a good generator is hard, but that is for OP to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know of a library you could re-use. That library would probably also lock you in on a particular approach to binding constructs, like De Bruijn, Names, (P)HOAS or `bound`.

I however know of an implementation in Haskell that does generate close, well-typed terms randomly: https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-Morte-Library/blob/3c61df86985a7ccf97fe0765deac73f06b12c476/test/ClosedWellTyped.hs#L38

Maybe this is enough to get you rolling?